# Focus on next element on ENTER key in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

in angularJs ENTER key has the predefined functionality of submitting the Form , i want change that to transfer the focus to the next element of the FORM i have the following directive which is working fine with the single row of the table in form i.e"" but its not transferring focus to the next row of the table and i have multiple tables in my form here is the directive

```
`app.directive('focusenter', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope,elem,attrs) {

      elem.bind('keydown', function(e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code === 13) {
          e.preventDefault();
          elem.next().focus();
               }
      });
    }
  }
});
            `
```

how can i do the this ????

Comment: could you add code with plunkr or fiddle?

Comment: try using focusin() instead of focus(). focus() is basically for input type elements.

Comment: @YashikaGarg  i am trying to achieve the same ,i mean  transferring focus from one input type element to other input type element i.e a textbox.